# Embed AnyLogic simulation already running

Tags: javascript, html, api, anylogic

I need to embed an already running AnyLogic model simulation in my web app.

The [official documentation](https://anylogic.help/cloud/embed-model-animation.html) describes how to embed a model into the web app using the iframe tag, specifying the `modelId` as a query parameter:

```html
<iframe width="1000" height="650" allow="fullscreen"
src="https://cloud.anylogic.com/assets/embed?modelId=7d49a08e-2641-42a9-bf0a-11b2dffe1408"
></iframe>
```

Is there any way to also specify the experimentRunId so that I can get the real-time animation of an already running simulation?
I tried using query parameters like `runId`, `experimentRunId` and `experimentId` (which are similar to the key returned by the Animation API when you start the model, link [here](https://anylogic.help/cloud/api/rest.html#animation-svg-run-info-object)) but none of them works.

The run ID is taken from the Animation SVG Run info which is a JSON structure like this one:

```json
{
    "animationHeight": 600,
    "animationSpeed": 10,
    "animationWidth": 1000,
    "experimentRunId": "fbc6a1d8-fa08-4a5c-a171-4631657c1aa7",
    "modelUuid": "493e6789-acf7-4dac-971d-325cb508ea39",
    "restUrl": "b0cc221b-8217-474b-af18-c2d07753187b/",
    "sessionUuid": "b0cc221b-8217-474b-af18-c2d07753187b",
    "version": "8.5.0"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Cloud API](https://anylogic.help/cloud/api/index.html#about-cloud-api), where this is possible to use different [client class methods](https://anylogic.help/cloud/api/js.html#cloudclient-class). [Custom User Interface built for a Cloud-based AnyLogic Model](https://cloud.anylogic.com/custom-ui-demo/index.html) tutorial may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible. But you should have current running Animation SVG Run info object and reuse inner method of JavaScript API.

```
const animationRunInfo = YOUR_RUN_INFO;
cloudClient._loadContentToDiv(HOST_URL + "/assets/svg/svg-template.html", "animation-container").then(() => {
  const svgClient = SVGFactory.createClient(animationRunInfo.version);
  const animation = new Animation(cloudClient, svgClient, null, animationRunInfo);
  animationRunInfo.host = HOST_URL;
  svgClient.setCallback("onstop", () => animation.stop());
  svgClient.start(animationRunInfo);
    return Promise.resolve(animation);
})
.then(animation => {
  return animation.waitForCompletion();
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error( error );
})
.finally(() => {});
```